# Spring @Transactional gets stuck inner a GCP Pub/Sub async Subscriber

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, transactions, publish-subscribe

I'm developing a process where It listens to a GCP pub/sub topic through an async Subscriber. When a message arrives, the Subscriber class call a @Service class which has DAOs to save data in a postgreSQL database.

The problem is the process gets stuck when the Receiver class invokes a @Service class' method annotated with @Transactional.

I have tried the following:

- Removing the @Transactional annotation from method and using an asynchronous Subscriber, it works.
- Using the @Transactional annotation and a synchronous Subscriber instead an asynchronous subscriber, It works.

I'm aware that an asynchronous subscription uses daemon threads and I think it is the reason that the process gets stuck.

I debugged the process and I noticed It got stuck in a class named CglibAopProxy

Here are the code with the approach I'm using, it was modified for simplifying reasons:

```
@Component
public class Subscriber {
    
    private void listen() {
        
        Subscriber subscriber = null;
        try {
            subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver)
                    .build();
            subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
            subscriber.awaitTerminated();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("An error ocurred listening messages : ", e);
        }
    }
}


@Component
public class Receiver implements MessageReceiver {
        
    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
        
        Event event = gson.fromJson(message.getData().toStringUtf8(), Event.class);
        service.create(event);
        
    }

}

@Service
public class Service {

    @Transactional
    public void create(Event event) {
        DAO1.save();
        DAO2.save();
        DAO3.save();
        DAO4.save();
    }

}
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you receiving errors or just getting stucked?. In case you are receiving errors, can you please share the error message?

Comment: It is just getting stucked, no errors are shown

Comment: (Don't express sorrow for not having the command of English one expects from an adult who learnt it as a first language. Get the help of a spelling checker, though.)

Comment: It seems that it could be related to the source code and I suggest you to raise also an issue directly in the Spring repo to get support from the team that handles it. Also, as no errors are shown, maybe you could try to use a profiler to get a stack trace from a stuck thread. This would help to narrow down the root cause.